# Variable is not getting passed

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I need to happen is have the top5 variable array get used for my index page. As of right now it says its an undefined variable. So with the if statement that assigns the page variable it needs to know to send the top5 variable array with it IF its the index page its going to load. When I do a print_r of the top5 variable in the controller it shows up like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [character_name] => Kid Wonder ) [1] => Array ( [character_name] => Ryu Satoshi ) [2] => Array ( [character_name] => Oriel ) [3] => Array ( [character_name] => "The Ladies Man" Luscious Landon ) [4] => Array ( [character_name] => "The Outlaw" Mike Mayhem ) )
```

Controller:

```
$siteInfo = $this->site->getSiteTitleAndSlogan();
$activeTemplate = $this->site->getTemplate();
if ($this->site->pageStatus('index', $activeTemplate[0]->id) == 1){
    $page = $this->load->view($activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/pages/index', '', true); 
} else {
    $page = $this->load->view($activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/pages/404', '', true); 
}
$footerLinks = $this->site->getFooterNav(); 
$top5 = $this->site->getTop5(); 
print_r($top5);
$this->template
->title($siteInfo[0]->site_name,$siteInfo[0]->site_slogan)
->prepend_metadata('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/assets/css/'.$activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'.css" />')
->set('footerLinks', $footerLinks)
->set('page', $page)
->set('top5', $top5)               
->set_partial('header', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/header')
->set_partial('navigation', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/navigation')            
->set_partial('content', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/content')
->set_partial('footer', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/footer')
->build('kow');
```

**EDIT :**

Here's my template system.

```
/views
/views/kow.php (template file)
/views/v1 (current template version)/
/views/v1/header.php
/views/v1/footer.php
/views/v1/navigation.php
/views/v1/content.php
/views/v1/pages/
/views/v1/pages/index.php(homepage)
/views/v1/pages/404.php(error page)
```

Content View:

```
<div id="content">
    <?php 
    echo $page; 
    ?>
</div>
```

Index Page View:

```
<div id="left">

<div id="spotlight">
    <img id="spotlight" src="assets/images/spotlight.png" alt="Kansas Outlaw Wrestling" />
</div>

<div id="top5">
    <ol>
        <?php 
        for ($i = 0; $i >= count($top5); $i++){
            foreach($top5[$i] as $row)
            {
                $seperator = ($elements == $count) ? '' : '<hr />'; 
                $name = (!isset($row['character_name'])) ? 'TBD' : $row['character_name'];
                $count++;
            ?>
                <li><span class="red"><?php echo $name; ?></span></li>
            <?php
         }
        }
        ?>

    </ol>
</div>

</div>

<div id="middle">
    <div id="topnews">
        <img id="topnewspic" src="assets/images/kelly.png" alt="Top News Pic" valign="right" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet mauris et erat luctus faucibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc sollicitudin ultricies nisi vel blandit. Quisque tincidunt mattis lacinia. Maecenas porttitor magna eu velit hendrerit ornare. Donec ultrices porttitor tellus sed venenatis. Integer ipsum lacus, malesuada eget ornare vel, mollis vel metus. Fusce a orci sed dui accumsan luctus et id enim. Aenean ac dui orci. Nam fringilla rutrum libero eget laoreet. Mauris ac sem metus, a ultrices ante. Duis quam metus, rhoncus sed dictum vel, ultricies vel nibh. Pellentesque enim lorem, mollis ut lacinia ac, aliquet id magna. Proin ante sapien, molestie in tincidunt hendrerit, blandit ut dolor. In rhoncus convallis ullamcorper. Integer sed arcu vitae libero dapibus interdum.</p>
        <p>Sed nibh leo, consequat non tempor vitae, fringilla eget augue. Pellentesque libero turpis, lobortis euismod consectetur eu, ultrices non orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed et nunc orci. Aliquam semper tortor in nunc placerat pulvinar. Etiam placerat ornare metus, id malesuada mi venenatis quis. Suspendisse dapibus, metus sollicitudin dictum aliquet, nisi dui tempus felis, a tristique sem est at ligula. Praesent commodo dolor ac ante ornare id cursus tellus luctus. Vivamus pretium metus ut dui hendrerit tincidunt.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="right">

    <div id="upcomingevents">

        <ul>
            <li>Warpath<span class="red">October 31, 2011</span></li>
            <hr />
            <li>Warpath<span class="red">October 31, 2011</span></li>
            <hr />
            <li>Warpath<span class="red">October 31, 2011</span></li>
            <hr />
            <li>Warpath<span class="red">October 31, 2011</span></li>
            <hr />
            <li>Warpath<span class="red">October 31, 2011</span></li>
        </ul> 

    </div>

    <div id="poll">
        <p id="question" class="red">How is it coming along?</p>
    </div>  

</div>
```

**EDIT 2 :**

Controller:

```
$siteInfo = $this->site->getSiteTitleAndSlogan();
        $activeTemplate = $this->site->getTemplate();
        if ($this->site->pageStatus('index', $activeTemplate[0]->id) == 1){
            $page = $this->load->view($activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/pages/index', '', true);  
        } else {
            $page = $this->load->view($activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/pages/404', '', true); 
        }
        $footerLinks = $this->site->getFooterNav(); 
        $toprankings = $this->site->getTop5();
        //$top5 = Array ( Array ( "character_name" => "Kid Wonder" ), Array ( "character_name" => "Ryu Satoshi" ), Array ( "character_name" => "Oriel" ), Array ( "character_name" => "\"The Ladies Man\" Luscious Landon" ), Array ( "character_name" => "\"The Outlaw\" Mike Mayhem" ));
        $data['$toprankings']=$toprankings;
        $this->template
        ->title($siteInfo[0]->site_name,$siteInfo[0]->site_slogan)
        ->prepend_metadata('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/assets/css/'.$activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'.css" />')
        ->set('footerLinks', $footerLinks)
        ->set('page', $page)
        ->set('toprankings', $toprankings)               
        ->set_partial('header', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/header')
        ->set_partial('navigation', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/navigation')            
        ->set_partial('content', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/content', $data)
        ->set_partial('footer', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/footer')
        ->build('kow');
```

View:

```
<?php

for($i=0;$i < count($toprankings); $i++) 
{
   echo "character_name: ".$toprankings[$i]['character_name']."<br>";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is backwards.

```
for ($i = 0; $i >= count($top5); $i++){
```

should be

```
for($i=0;$i<count($top5);$i++)
```

`$i` starts at `0` and therefore will never be more than `count` and even if it is equal will never increment nor iterate.

---

Try deleting everything in your view except the top5 part, and change that to:

```
<?php 
    for($i=0;$i<count($top5);$i++)
    {
        foreach($top5[$i] as $k=>$v)
        {
        echo $k."   =    ".$v."<BR>";
        }
    }
?>
```

just to see if it's working. Also, it'd help to know what templating system you are using.

Comment: Because that still gives me a undefined variable message.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with `$this->site->getTop5(); ` or there is something wrong in the template. If you can see it with `print_r()`, it has been defined.

Comment: its not because when I do a print_r($top5) it returns the right results like I said above. Has to deal with it getting passed correctly.

Comment: Can we see your view where you're calling `$top5` and its saying undefined?

Comment: Your for loop is backwards. Updated answer above.

Comment: I'm still getting that undefined variable.

Comment: Its not getting to the view so that's the issue.

Comment: I tested it out using straight views and it works `$data['top5']=$top5;`. Try changing the variable name. Also, it doesn't look like the names will print as expected. I updated my answer.

Comment: If you can send me a IM on AIM or yahoo. sn: xtremer360

Comment: I don't have chat. Try renaming the variable to $top5test or something in both the view and controller. if $page is getting through there is no reason why $top5 shouldn't unless it isn't being set in site->getTop5() or it is being unset/overwritten somewhere.

Comment: because $page is for the content.php include and then through the $page variable is the $top5 variable so it has a middle page it has to fight through.

Comment: Try `$data['top5']=$top5;` then `->build('kow',$data);'

Comment: Dunno brah. What are you using for templating?

Comment: Try `$data['top5']=$top5;` and `template->set_partial('content', $activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/content',$data)`

Comment: What do I do wiht this: ->set('top5', $top5)

Comment: Well i tried it with it and I tried it with that line commented out and nothing worked.

Comment: I think your general setup might be off somewhere. I dloaded the library, tested and those variables (page, footerLinks, top5) are all available in the layout file via $page, $footerLinks, and $top5. Try changing the variable name.

Comment: Change which variable name and in where?

Comment: The layout file being the default that is set in config/template.php which you're using here as set_layout() is not set.

Comment: Change $top5 to something else in the controller and view

Comment: Trying to up your rep so you could join chat here, but no dice. As far as I understand, You are using the default layout defined in config/template.php as there is no set_layout defined in the controller. In that file, $top5 should be accessible via $top5

Comment: I edited my post. Still no matter what I'm getting the same error message with undefined variable.

Comment: what is `$config['layout']` set to?

Comment: OK, then in default.php $top5 will be accessible as $top5. This is why I think there is a fundamental issue with how the templates are set up. Open up default.php and put in print_r($top5). Or in the controller, add set_layout('test') then create test.php in your view folder and print_r($top5) from there.

Comment: i don't have a default.php layout

Comment: I think your refering to my kow.php file which is inside the views which tells where my partials to be placed.

Comment: Dunno man. On a fresh CI install with that library installed, if $config['layout'] = 'default'; it looks for default.php and if it doesn't find it it throws an error. If I use ->set_layout('test') it looks for test.php instead of default.php. Unless site-> is doing something, there should be a default.php file somewhere that is being used. kow is called via build() not config['layout']

Comment: hmm odd oh well its caused so many issues. I'm going to dump the template system. Do you suggest one that actually works.

Comment: I think it'll work, but you have to use it correctly. I don't have experience with it (obviously), but Phil writes good stuff. Try this: take all your code out of kow.php and in application/views create folder layouts and in there create a file test.php paste kow code in there then in controller ->set_layout('test') and see what happens

Comment: its more trouble then its worth. THanks for your effort though

Comment: Roger, thanks. If you're going to start over, check out [pyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com/). It's got a great module system and the template stuff is already set up. You can build off what's there.

Comment: well I"m building my own because the stuff I need it for is for my uses and its not stuff i'd find on there.